# How to remove rows with function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with I want to remove some rows.

I have a function which decide if we need to remove the row or not

for example (just example, not the actual logic):

```
def is_valid(val):
   if val >= 50:
       return True
   return False
```

I want to run the function on the `TRR` column (`df['TRR']` ) and remove all rows which apply False from `is_valid` function.

How can we do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `True` means remove rows use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), here `~` is for intert mask for keep `False` rows:

```
df = df[~df['TRR'].apply(is_valid)]
```

If `True` means keep rows use:

```
df = df[df['TRR'].apply(is_valid)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to modify the function you could try:

```
def is_valid(val):
   return val >= 50

df[is_valid(df['TRR'])]
```